Quarkus 3.9 return object with response code
I'm developing an application with a Contract First approach.
one of my paths:
  /game/init:
    post:
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/initGame'
      tags:
        - Game
      summary: Initialize a game
      description: Initialize a game
      operationId: initializeGame
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Game was created
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/gameIdentifier'

As you can see I want to return an HTTP 201 here to indicate that the Game has been initialized.
This gets generated to
@Path("/game/init")

@jakarta.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.JavaJAXRSSpecServerCodegen", date = "2024-05-17T14:16:48.789874400+02:00[Europe/Brussels]")
public interface GameApi {
        /**
    * Initialize a game
    *
    * @param initGame 
    * @return Game was created - 201

    */

    @ResponseStatus(201)
    @POST
    @Consumes({ "application/json" })
    @Produces({ "text/plain" })
    Long initializeGame(@Valid @NotNull InitGame initGame);
}

which is an interface I'm implementing elsewhere.
due to an issue with RestEasy (https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/30170) I've tried to adapt the mustache templates to include the @ResponseStatus(201), since by default there was no code generated for it.
This has no effect on my application, and still returns a 200.
I've additionally tried with RestResponse and Response, which gives ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl cannot be cast to class org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.jaxrs.RuntimeDelegateImpl 
Which I haven't been able to resolve.
It seems that I'm doing something terribly wrong, since such a central functionality shouldn't be this hard.
for completeness sake, I'll include my pom here as well:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>company</groupId>
    <artifactId>battleship</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.12.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>21</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>3.9.5</quarkus.platform.version>
        <skipITs>true</skipITs>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.2.5</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.parser.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-parser</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-reactive-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Flyway specific dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-flyway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JDBC driver dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.mkammerer.snowflake-id</groupId>
            <artifactId>snowflake-id</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi/battleship.yml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>jaxrs-spec</generatorName>
<!--                            <verbose>true</verbose>-->
                            <templateResourcePath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi-templates</templateResourcePath>

                            <configOptions>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <useSwaggerAnnotations>false</useSwaggerAnnotations>
                                <!--ensure we only generate java interfaces and no implementation skeleton-->
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <useTags>true</useTags>
                                <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                            </configOptions>
                            <apiPackage>company.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>company.beans</modelPackage>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                            <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <auth>false</auth>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
<!--            maven helper plugin to add generated sources to maven project-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/openapi/src/gen/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <skipITs>false</skipITs>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>



The solution I've started using is to adapt the mustache templates so that the generated code expects a RestResponse.
Then, using the RestResponseBuilder, I can set the desired HTTP Response Code, including an object to my desire, while still having it strongly typed.
I test everything with RestAssured.
